# Apache + PHP Memory Limit Upload Issue

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php5

My environment is Fedora 20, Apache 2.4.10, and php 5.5.26 and I am having an issue with uploading a file that is greater than 2 GB's.  If I upload a file greater than 2 gb's I'm noticing that while uploading apache's child process's memory bloats up to the 2 gb limit and I'll get a segfault and the upload will restart.  If I set my php memory limit to < 2 GB's I will see the upload complete however then I will have a PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxx exhausted.  On our dev server apache's child process does not have memory bloat and the upload works properly with all the same php.ini and apache settings.  I am at a loss for what might be causing this and I am hoping someone will have some other ideas to look at.

**PHP.INI**

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 9600M
upload_max_filesize = 9500M
post_max_size = 9500M
```

**httpd.conf**

```
Timeout 600
```

Comment: First bring your system current. Fedora 20 was end of life almost a year ago.

Comment: What does your PHP script look like? IIRC, then Apache should be saving the file in chunks onto the HDD and once it is done then it merely supplies the temp path to PHP. The error `Allowed memory size of xxx exhausted` makes me 99% sure that your PHP script is loading the entire file into PHP's memory after it's been uploaded. Large files should never be an issue unless you are loading them into memory.

Comment: I didn't realize I was at end of life already so thank you for pointing that out.  I would agree it seems it is loading it all into memory but I have plenty to spare.  I modified my upload_max_filesize to 2048M as well as post_max_size to 2048M and the upload appears to be working properly even uploading files that are greater than 2 GB.  I noticed this when looking at my dev/test servers and seeing that they were set to 2048M and working properly.  Riddle me that one...  I'm checking to make sure the files did not get corrupted however with the upload.  Will report back when I know.